# How to get the cutscene where motherbase staff fights each other in MGSV?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

*Please make the answer for this question as unspoilery as possible.*

I am about two-thirds into the main missions in The Phantom Pain and I've felt a need to get the cutscene from the trailer where:

> two Diamond Dog mercenaries fight each other, then one of them pulls a knife and Big Boss steps in to stop them.

**Does this cutscene just happen at a specific point of time during regular gameplay and if not, how do you trigger it?**

Comment: I'm only at 11% completion and just reached this scene.  I basically did every single side op available and did 9 of the main missions (skipped 7 and 8).  After capturing a particular soldier, I saw that scene after 2 or 3 visits (that opened with cutscenes) back to mother base. What triggered it? Don't know, but I figure you need to visit mother base regularly to trigger these scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cut-scene happens when morale drops to a very low point at Motherbase. Morale will decrease over time when you have not visited it in a while. Sometimes you will get certain events that trigger it additionally and you will see "Morale has decreased" on the screen in the notification area.

For those interested the cut-scene is here: [Low Morale MGS5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifY5kktFw44)

Answer (score 0):

I think it triggers when morale in low. Spent to much 
GMP and went into the red without noticing.

Answer (score 0):

One thing just comes to my mind, that having staff with the Troublemaker skill might just help here, in addition to having low morale. ;3